# Fusion Layer not showing data when querying against a text column

Tags: google-fusion-tables

https://gist.github.com/2017706

The HTML file at the gist above will successfully load the data from the referenced fusion table into a map layer, yet when I try to query against the Name column (yes I know columns are case-sensitive in queries) I get the "Data may still be loading" error displayed, yet clearing the input box to reset the layer without a query works again.

I got this to work with a small fusion table created manually, the only difference with this data is that it was imported from an Excel file.  Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem falls at the following line:

```
select: 'Latitude,Longitude',
```

In a table with a 2-column location, you only need to select the one column that was marked as a Location. In this case, it appears to be your Latitude column. Try updating the above line to the following, and see if that works:

```
select: 'Latitude',
```